# send data from PHP accessed by http through websocket server

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

**The problem:**

Ok, now the user send data through normal HTTP request to the server,
PHP did the process needed and fetch the result from the database, now I want to send these data back to a user throughout WS instead of HTTP.

**Used technology:**

PHP & Ratchet

JS

**Code:**

Normal websocket ran by command

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Receiver()
            )
        ),
        env('CHAT_PORT',8080)
    );

    $server->run();
```

and the receiver has a property called `$userAuthSocketMapper` which map between the Authentication key of the user (the http side) and the resourceId (the ws side).

**What am thinking of:**

If i only can get the `Receiver` instance which ran by Ratchet, I can easily access its resourceId property and its send method to send the data to the user i want. but how to get that instance when user send http request instead of ws request !